# How to fix last bone in armature?

Tags: armature, bones

I have a small trouble with the last armature(Situation "b" on the screenshot below). They bend with all chains. I use **IK constraint** and it does not include the first bone from the left. But not the last. I solve this problem by **Copy Rotation** bone constraint (Situation "a" on the screenshot below) and rotate the target bone because my ending Empties will be animated in the future (will change position and rotation). So, **Limit Rotation** constraint and unchecked **Inherit Rotation** checkbox is not my variant.

But I think that is not the best solution. Maybe this situation has another more ellegant solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your bone chain with a spline IK, which is a different bone constraint than the standard IK. In Object Mode, create a path with *Add* > *Curve* > *Path*. Adjust it in Edit Mode to take the shape you want. Return to Object Mode and select your bone chain, then switch to Pose Mode. Go to the *Bone Constraints* Tab in the Properties Panel to create a **Spline IK** constraint. Give it the curve path you already created as its *target*. Provide the maximum number of bones to be effected, which presumably, is all of them in your case. After doing this, you can manipulate your bone chain by moving the control points of the path curve while in Edit Mode.

To keyframe changes to this rig, you will need a hook modifier. In Object Mode, create an empty and snap it at the outermost tip of your "1 position" bone. Select this empty, then hold  <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and select the Spline also, then go into Edit Mode, select the end point of the path which is closest to the "1 position" bone. Finally, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to bring up the Hook menu. From the list, choose **Hook to Selected Object**. Now your rig will follow your empty, and you can keyframe the position of the empty in Object Mode.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!